# Trying to print in gimp

Tags: gimp

When I try to print in Gimp, it goes to save a file. I want it to go to my printer not my computer as a prn file. I've tried changing setting and looked at every button I can find.

Comment: Have you chosen your printer and not "Print to file" option? Can you print from other programs?

Answer (score -2):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> when the Gimp window is active. It should resolve your problem.

Comment: Ctrl-P uses the default printer selection.  If Print to File is selected, it will still use that.